# C++11 class with union of string and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, discriminated-union

(this is a bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693913/c11-anonymous-union-with-non-trivial-members), and inspired by the [C++11 FAQ on union](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions) but not exactly so...)

In the context of coding a Scheme-like interpreter in idiomatic C++11 Let's suppose I want a tagged union of a string, an int, and some closure. So I would probably code:

```
#include <string>
#include <new>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
enum kind { nothing, string, integer, closure };

class Value {
 enum kind k;
 typedef std::string string_t;
  union {
    std::string str;
    int num;
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<Value(std::vector<Value>)>> clos;
  };
public:
 Value (const Value &v) 
 : k(none) {
   switch (v.k) {
   case none: break;
   case string: new(&str)string_t(v.str); break;
   case integer: num = v.num; break; 
   /// what about closure-s?
   }
   k = v.k;
 };
 Value& operator = (const Value&v) {
   switch (v.k) {
    case none: break;
    case string: new(&str)string_t(v.str); break;
    case integer: num = v.num; break; 
    /// what about closure-s?
   }
  k = v.k;
 }
 /// etc...
};
```

Now what about the `closure` case? For the copy constructor and the assignment operator, I am tempted to code:

```
 case closure: clos = v.clos; break;
```

But perhaps should I use a placement `new` on a `shared_ptr`?

I don't want to use Boost (or any non standard C++11 library) for that purpose.

Comment: Why are you hesitating to use placement `new` for the `shared_ptr` as for the `string`? I don't think that assignment of a `shared_ptr` to uninitialized memory is safe. It will potentially try to destruct the “managed object” of some garbage bits. Oh, and in the copy-assignment operator you should destroy the `string` before re-constructing it or it will leak the old buffer.

Comment: This probably deserves to become an answer, not a comment....

Comment: If you do not want to use Boost directly you should at least learn from there how it is done type safe way in `boost::variant` and use similar methods ie visitor pattern instead of switch etc. At least you will detect if visitor does not handle all variants at compile rather than runtime in your case.

Comment: @Slava Given that the question is about C++11's `union`s, I don't think that `boost:variant` is a good source of inspiration because a large part of its purpose is to work around the restrictions that were in place for `union`s before C++11 relaxed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason not to use placement `new` for the `std::shared_ptr` just as you did for the `std::string`.  Simply assigning a value as in

```
clos = v.clos;
```

is not safe as it will call the copy-assignment operator of `std::shared_ptr`  with a `this` pointer that potentially points to garbage memory.  It might try to `delete` something that isn't there.

Likewise, in your copy-assignment operator, you should destroy the old object before you emplace the new one or the old value will leak.

```
using std::string;
using std::shared_ptr;
if (&v == this)
  return *this;  // self-assignment
switch (this->k)
  {
  case string:
    this->str.~string();
    break;
  case closure:
    this->clos.~shared_ptr();
    break;
  }
this->k = nothing;
// Now we are ready to take the new value.
```

The code will probably become easier to maintain if you use the [*copy & swap* idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/1392132).  Since I don't see any obvious performance gains of not using it, I don't think it will cost you anything extra here.