# Attempting to reference a deleted function error with anonymous union

Tags: c++

```
struct Dingus {
union {
    int dingly[4 *4];
    vec3 dinglyDo;
}diddly;
inline Dingus() {}
};
```

This code produces the error

```
error C2280: 'Dingus::<unnamed-type-diddly>::<unnamed-type-diddly>(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Oddly, when I delete the "diddly" which was giving a reference to the union, there is no error.

The vec3 is a struct from the GLM library, I can replace the type with some other classes and i'll get the same error... but if I replace it with something simple like float I don't get the error

Since removing the "diddly" removes the error, this seems to be a different question than this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693913/c11-anonymous-union-with-non-trivial-members)

Comment: @LogicStuff It's a struct from the GLM library, I can replace the type with some other things and i'll get the same error... but if I replace it with something simple like float I don't get the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 anonymous union with non-trivial members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693913/c11-anonymous-union-with-non-trivial-members)

Comment: What does _"delete the "diddly", thereby giving a name to reference the union with"_ mean? You changed `union { ... } diddly;` to `union Foo { ... };`? Because if so, that means something completely different, so the `Dingus` constructor doesn't try to default-initialize an object of that type, and so it's not odd at all that it compiles.

Comment: @JonathanWakely sorry I made it more clear. I meant to say, when I turn `union { ... } diddly;` into `union { ... }`, there is no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared a member of that anonymous union type, and so the member needs to be initialized in the `Dingus` constructor. Because the union has a member of non-trivial type it has no default constructor, so it can't be initialized in the `Dingus` constructor.

You can define a constructor for the union type which says what should happen when it's default-constructed e.g.

```
struct Dingus {
  union U {
    int dingly[4 *4];
    vec3 dinglyDo;
    U() : dingly() { }
  } diddly;
  inline Dingus() {}
};
```

Comment: @KerrekSB Maybe this comment is what pushed them over the edge. [variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: Yes. The committee was undedicdedly puzzling over whether to spend time on exploring new directions that were being floated at the time, such as "nodules", "percepts" and "unicorn call syntax", but when this comment came in, everything was dropped and national bodies aligned behind the Convener in Chief and started sending in paper after paper in support of variant. Some warned that we'd we working on variant for the next twenty years. There was laughter.

Answer (score 0):

As of `c++17` you can use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of a union to solve this problem. Your code could easily be replaced by:

```
struct Dingus {
    std::variant<std::array<int, 4*4>, vec3> diddly;
    inline Dingus() {}
};
```

Comment: You can't store an array in a `std::variant`, use a `std::array`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Although i changed it, and i don't know how you would even use an array, it does compile ... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c4c50ffbc38722b